# How to pass dynamic arguments to parametric LESS mixin?

Tags: less

I have been playing around with parametric LESS mixins, and I have to say I am quite pleased with the flexibility so far. My question is as titled, but for some context, this is what I am attempting to achieve:

```css
.animation-factory(@name; @from; @to) {
  @keyframes @name {
    from {
      @from();
    }
    to {
      @to();
    }
  }
  animation: @name 0.5s ease-in-out forwards;
}

.opacity-factory(@value) {
  '@opacity-${value}': {
    opacity: @value;
  };
}
```

Then, in some other bit of LESS code for fading in an element, for example:

```css
#my-element {
  opacity: 0;
  &.active {
    .animation-factory(
      show-my-element,
      .opacity-factory(0),
      .opacity-factory(1)
    ); 
  }
 }
```

The reason I want to be able to do this is that I find I am creating a lot of ruleset boilerplate code, so being able to dynamically generate it would be more attractive.

Is this possible?

Comment: "Dynamic arguments" - pretty unclear title (by "dynamic" they started to cover anything and ended to mean nothing at all). Your example is clean enough though - it looks like you probably need ["Passing Rulesets to Mixins"](http://lesscss.org/features/#detached-rulesets-feature) you already use, just swap the mixins up-side-down (see [examples](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/613b9b868001d75378c06d397159d016)). As for the exact code in you example: no, mixins can't *return* values so you can't use mixins calls as args (Though there's support for *functions* available via plugins).

Comment: Example 3 is exactly what I am trying to achieve. Thanks! I used this instead: http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22div%20%7B%5Cn%20%20.animation(opacity%2C%20opacity%2C%200%2C%201)%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn.animation(%40name%2C%20%40property%2C%20%40from%2C%20%40to)%20%7B%5Cn%5Ctanimation%3A%20%40name%200.5s%20ease-in-out%20forwards%3B%5Cn%5Ct%40keyframes%20%40name%20%7B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ctfrom%20%7B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%40%7Bproperty%7D%3A%20%40from%3B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%7D%5Cn%5Ct%5Ctto%20%7B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%40%7Bproperty%7D%3A%20%40to%3B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%7D%5Cn%5Ct%7D%5Cn%7D%22%7D

Which brings me to another Q...

Comment: Is it possible to use quoted strings like: http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22div%20%7B%5Cn%20%20.animation(opacity%2C%200%2C%201)%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn.animation(%40property%2C%20%40from%2C%20%40to)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20animation%3A%20'animate-%40%7Bproperty%7D'%200.5s%20ease-in-out%20forwards%3B%5Cn%20%20%40keyframes%20'animate-%40%7Bproperty%7D'%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20from%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%40%7Bproperty%7D%3A%20%40from%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20to%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%40%7Bproperty%7D%3A%20%40to%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%22%7D

Comment: I cannot get this to work on codepen.io: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zdNaBB

Comment: Your version is not working because there're you try `'animate-@{property}'` thing in invalid places.

Comment: Here's the [proper way](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22div%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20.animation(opacity%2C%200%2C%201)%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn.animation(%40property%2C%20%40from%2C%20%40to)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%40name%3A%20~'animate-%40%7Bproperty%7D'%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20animation%3A%20%40name%200.5s%20ease-in-out%20forwards%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%40keyframes%20%40name%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%200%25%20%7B%40%7Bproperty%7D%3A%20%40from%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20to%20%7B%40%7Bproperty%7D%3A%20%40to%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%22%7D).

Comment: Bloody perfect! Thanks for the help! Please put that in an answer so I can credit you for it. :^)